# Problem extracting code into a Use Case for Clean Architecture

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, clean-architecture, event-driven

I am consuming a message from a queue and I want to be able to perform the same logic from an API request, so I am trying to extract a use case from my `OnMessage()` method.

```cs
public class QueueListener
{
    public void OnMessage(Message message)
    {
        var thing = _apiClient.GetThing(message.Id);
        var stuff = _repository.GetStuff(message.Id);

        stuff.PutAThingInStuff(thing);
        _repository.SaveStuff(stuff);

        _outQueue.SendOutgoingMessage(new Message(message.Id));
        _apiClient.SetThingToComplete(message.Id);
    }
}
```

However, the order of `.SendOutgoingMessage()` and marking the `.SetThingToComplete()` has me second guessing.  Sending to the outgoing queue is only implemented when the use case is called from the queue, not when called from the API.  The API will simply return the result of the use case.  Also, the *order is significant*, were we don't want to mark the thing complete if didn't successfully post it to the outgoing queue (I'm aware that I can't guarantee there wasn't an error returning the result to the consumer of the API).

I am not sure what the right approach is here, I *feel* like `.SetThingToComplete()` belongs in the Use Case because that should happened regardless of where its called.

I thought using a presenter in this case might make sense, however I'm worried that adding a specific order to `.Present()` and `.SetThingToComplete()` might add implicit coupling and be a leaky abstraction.

```cs
public class UseCase
{
    public void Handle(Request request, IPresenter presenter)
    {
        var thing = _apiClient.GetThing(request.MessageId);
        var stuff = _repository.GetStuff(request.MessageId);

        stuff.PutAThingInStuff(thing);
        _repository.SaveStuff(stuff);

        // does having a specific order here implicitly add coupling?
        presenter.Present(new Result(request.MessageId));
        _apiClient.SetThingToComplete(request.MessageId);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class QueueListener
{
    public void OnMessage(Message message)
    {
        var presenter = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPresenter>();
        var useCase = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UseCase>();
        useCase.Handle(new Request(message.Id), presenter);
    }

    public class Presenter : IPresenter
    {
        private readonly IOutBoundQueue _outQueue;

        public void Present(Result result)
        {
            _outQueue.SendOutgoingMessage(new Message(result.MessageId));
        }
    }
}
```

I've thought that they might be two different use cases, however all the code is the same except that one line.  Thought about adding a flag to the `Request` to send to the queue or not but I don't like to add "configuration" properties to commands that aren't related to business logic.

I've also thought adding an additional EventHandler class for handling the event separate from calling the command itself or using a domain event instead, but the same problems present themselves in both cases.

Comment: I might be mistaken but feel like the content is a bit too abstract to be really relevant when we talk about _domain driven design_. Another question is about semantic. Isn't the fact that _apiClient is in fact an api client an implementation detail ? Is it really relevant to the business ? Isn't the transactionnal-ness of the process more interesting ? What should be done on SetThingToComplete's failure ? Is it a command or an event ?

Comment: Do you expect the calling of your operation through API to sent a message to the outgoing queue as well, or is this message only expected when handling an MQ message ?

Comment: @Pierre-AntoineGuillaume this may be more relevant to Clean Architecture than DDD.  The use case represents application layer code, which is stitching together the different business logic that resides in the domain.  `_apiClient.SetThingToComplete()` might be analogous to an integration event, however its still unclear to mean if it belongs in the use case or not.  The reason order is relevant in this case is if there was an error posting to the outgoing queue, there would be no reason to call `.SetThingToComplete()`.  Sending an event to the out queue is the implementation detail I think.

Comment: @ArwynFr Calling the operation through the API should not send to the outgoing queue.  Sending to the outgoing queue in this context would viewed the same returning a value via the API response.  If it comes in the queue, it goes out the queue, if it comes in via API request, it's returned via API response.

Comment: So you have a system with 2 components: C1 handles the use case and can be accessed via an API or a MQ ; C2 is accessible through another API ; when use case in C1 is trigger via MQ, you want to set the property in C2 *after* the outgoing message is sent ; when the use case in C1 is triggered via API nothing is done in C2. Is that correct ?

Comment: Partially correct, however I want to set the property in C2 regardless if being called from MQ or API.  But, I only want to send the outgoing message when called from MQ.  And when called from MQ, setting the property in C2 needs to be done _after_ sending the outgoing message.

Comment: Your distributed model seems to have consistency issues as it doesn't seem resilient to failures as it is. What happens if `_apiClient.SetThingToComplete` fails? You'd be left in an inconsistent state forever? You should most likely write an event like `ThingPutInStuff` which then would be asynchronously processed to call `_apiClient.SetThingToComplete` where the operation needs to be idempotent (at least once delivery). As for `SendOutgoingMessage` what does that do and why isin't that needed when called from the API?

Answer (score 0):

On possibility that you should seriously consider is that you may not yet have enough information to create abstractions that are going to be healthy in the long term

> The wrong abstraction is far more damaging than no abstraction at all. Waiting trumps guessing every time. -- [Sandi Metz, 2012](https://twitter.com/sandimetz/status/273110526706462721)

One of the benefits you get from waiting is that you discover whether or not the two different places that are using the code actually do change for the same reasons.

---

But, assuming you have to guess *now*...

Part of the trick to decoupling is to share as little information as possible.

Passing *something* is the right idea:

```
public class QueueListener
{
    public void OnMessage(Message message)
    {
        var verb = this.verb(message.Id);
        var useCase = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UseCase>();
        useCase.Handle(message.Id, verb);
    }

    IVerb verb(Message.Id id)
    {
        return new Verber(this._outQueue, id)
    }

    public class Verber : IVerb
    {
        private readonly IOutBoundQueue _outQueue;
        private readonly Message.Id _id;

        Verber(IOutBoundQueue outQueue, Message.Id id)
        {
            this._outQueue = outQueue
            this._id = id
        }

        public void Verb()
        {
            _outQueue.SendOutgoingMessage(new Message(this._id));
        }
    }
}

public class UseCase
{
    public void Handle(Request request, IVerb verber)
    {
        var thing = _apiClient.GetThing(request.MessageId);
        var stuff = _repository.GetStuff(request.MessageId);

        stuff.PutAThingInStuff(thing);
        _repository.SaveStuff(stuff);

        verber.verb();

        _apiClient.SetThingToComplete(request.MessageId);
    }
}
```

So we can reduce (some of) the coupling by wrapping information specific to a specialization behind the abstraction, so that other parts of the code don't need to know about it (see Information Hiding in [Parnas 1971](https://prl.ccs.neu.edu/img/p-tr-1971.pdf)).

---

> does having a specific order here implicitly add coupling?

Sort of.

Your interfaces are manifestations of a contract, where the contract may include preconditions and postconditions beyond those expressed by the type system.

```
class UseCase : Contract.UseCase {...}

class QueueListener {
    class Verber : Contract.Verb { ... }
    ...
}
```

In a sense, the contract defines what it means to be a conforming participant in some interaction; participants that fail to meet their obligations under the contract are broken.

In other words, some of the "implicitness" here is simply a consequence of choosing a design where the contract is not explicit.

One example of an explicit contract that is likely to be familiar: HTTP.  HTTP components aren't tightly coupled to each other, but the are coupled to the *protocol* and the message semantics that have been standardized.

And for the most part, that's been really successful, because the HTTP contracts have been really stable, and in the places where the contracts have changed, they have been changed in a way that is backwards compatible.

But designing stable contracts is a hard problem, especially when we're exploring our first implementations, and are still in the dark about which kinds of changes we may need in the future.  This is made more challenging when the contracts are implicit; but when requirements are unstable an explicit contract definition is a lot of work to invest in a short lived artifact.

> Waiting trumps guessing every time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am familiar with Sandi's blog post about the wrong abstraction.  However, I'm not sure it applies here.  The Use Case is application layer code and represents a capability of the system.  We want to be able to execute that same capability regardless of how it's called.  The use case shouldn't contain business logic, it would be painless to duplicate it if needed.  I agree with you about contracts and stability, which is why the `IPresenter` would be defined in the same layer as the use case, slightly more stable that I/O.  Still less stable than domain logic.

Answer (score 0):

You are building your QueueListener on top of the API, but they should go side-by-side. They both should run the same use case, but they are two different *interface adapters*. All code that is related to use case handling is common and should go in the same UseCase and should be adapter agnostic:

```cs
public class UseCase
{
    public void Handle(Request request, IPresenter presenter)
    {
        var stuff = _repository.GetStuff(request.MessageId);
        stuff.PutAThingInStuff(thing);
        _repository.SaveStuff(stuff);
        presenter.Present(new Result(request.MessageId));
    }
}
```

Then have two adapters handle the communication:

```cs
public class QueueListener
{
    public void OnMessage(Message message)
    {
        var presenter = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPresenter>();
        var useCase = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UseCase>();
        useCase.Handle(new Request(message.Id), presenter);
    }

    public class QueuePresenter : IPresenter
    {
        private readonly IOutBoundQueue _outQueue;
        public void Present(Result result)
        {
            _outQueue.SendOutgoingMessage(new Message(result.MessageId));
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult OnPost([FromQuery] Message message)
    {
        var presenter = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPresenter>();
        var useCase = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UseCase>();
        presenter.Controller = this;
        useCase.Handle(new Request(message.Id), presenter);
        return presenter.Result;
    }

    public class ApiPresenter : IPresenter
    {
        public Controller Controller { get; set; }
        public IActionResult Result { get; private set; }
        public void Present(Result result)
        {
            Result = Controller.Ok(result.MessageId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, that I understand an agree with. It is one of the reasons I felt a Presenter would be useful here.  My question is if _order matters_, then is where to put the call `.SetThingToComplete()`?  Does that go in the Use Case _after_ `presenter.Present()` or should that belong in each implementation of the presenter?  In the case of the `QueuePresenter` , the call `.SetThingToComplete()` would happen _after_ `.SendOutgoingMessage()` and in the `ApiPresenter it would _only_ contain the call `.SetThingToComplete()` since we cannot confirm API response was successfully returned to the client.

Comment: What does the `SetThingToComplete()` do ? Why would you call it when called from the queue ?

Comment: It is a separate status on the message as part of an orchestration.  Once our API is done with processing, we post to the queue and only if we can post it to the queue, the message can be considered complete.  If we set it to complete prior to posting it in the queue, if there is a failure we're left in an in consistent state.

Comment: You mean it sets a property on the **domain** model as completed ?

Comment: No, it is setting the state of a model as complete in a 3rd party API.